# Sprintf with 3 arguments doesn't work

Tags: c++, printf

I'm working on a game modification, but a small part of my code appears to crash the game because of possible incorrect sprintf usage.

```
Menu& Menu::scroller(char** textArray, int* index, int numItems, bool fast) {
    char buffer[60];
    numItems--;

    if (hovered()) {
        lrInstruction = true;
        fastScrolling = fast;
        if (rightPress || (rightHold && fast)) {
            playSound("NAV_UP_DOWN");
            if (*index >= numItems) {
                *index = 0;
            }
            else {
                *index = *index + 1;
            }
        }
        else if (leftPress || (leftHold && fast)) {
            playSound("NAV_UP_DOWN");
            if (*index <= 0) {
                *index = numItems;
            }
            else {
                *index = *index - 1;
            }
        }
    }

    if (hovered()) {
        sprintf(buffer, "%s [%s/%s]", textArray[*index], *index, numItems);
        return data(buffer);
    }

    return data(textArray[*index]);
}
```

This is the original code I'm using, when I use this sprintf it crashes the game because of possible incorrect usage of the function.

When I do this:

```
sprintf(buffer, "%s", textArray[*index]);
```

It works perfectly fine. I've tried multiple things like `$2%s/$3%s` but that does not appear to do the trick.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `%s` expects a string, `*index` and `numItems` are not string. Turn on your warnings.

Comment: On a side note, using `sprintf` accounts for bizzare number of security exploits. Make sure to **never** use it and always use `snprintf`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"%s" means print a null terminated character string, if you want to print an integer use "%d".

Even better, unless you have a good reason not to, use c++ stringstreams, boost::format or other c++ type safe string formatting libraries.

Comment: I think, your last phrase needs some editing. Right now it reads like a suggestion to not use stringstreams, etc unless you have a good reason.

Comment: added some commas

Comment: Tried this `sprintf(buffer, "%s [%d/%s]", textArray[*index], *index, numItems);` but still doesn't seem to work

Comment: numItems is an integer too so you need `"%s [%d/%d]"`

Comment: Oh right, sorry. Tried it and it works. Got it noted for next time, thanks Alan!